# JAX-WS client closes tcp connection with FIN,ACK

Tags: java, web-services, tcp, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

We have implemented a JAX-WS client and facing the following issue.
It is a stateful session sync flow. The client makes two requests/response initially one by one sucessfully

**3 different Cases for the issue**

1) After the first two request/response, I am making a third request which is after 6th and 9th( two different test cases)  seconds after the receiving the response of 2nd request.
In both the cases, from the tcpdump I could see that our client is closing the existing tcp connection by [FIN,ACK] and opening a new connection for the 3rd request.
But since this is stateful session, the server expects the connection should not be cloased and so we are getting error response.

2) If I make the 3rd request within 5 seconds after 2nd request, then the same tcp connection is re-used.

3) If I dont make 3rd request at all, then automatcially after 10 seconds(by [FIN,ACK] from the 2nd request, the tcp conenction is closed by the client.

Basically the problem is client application is closing the tcp connection by itself.
I have tried by setting all the following properties. But still I am facing the same problem.

```
   BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)port;
   Map<String, Object> context = bp.getRequestContext();
  context.put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);

  context.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 60000);
  context.put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 70000);

  context.put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 50000);
  context.put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 50000);

  context.put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", 60000);
  context.put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", 70000);
```

I am attching the screenshot of pcap file for your reference. Here you can see [FIN,ACK] issued by client after 6 seconds.
[image]

I am not sure if there is any other config which I am missing. Can you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Vesrions:
Java :  jdk1.6.0_21

Metro : Metro/2.3

HTTP:  1.1

One more thing I have noticed is, there is a "Connection: keep-alive" in request but its not there in server's response. Not sure if this could be a problem

Comment: Hi.  I am having the exact same problem but in my case the client stub is closing the connection after 15 seconds.  Did you find any solution?

Comment: @IgorZelaya nope..I did not had time to check further as the issue was escalated. I gave an workaround by sending a dummy message like ping if there are no actual traffic for more than 4 or 5 seconds. That way I saved the connection from getting closed.

Comment: Are you certain it is the jax-ws client itself and not a proxy or device between client & service provider with an inactivity timeout, such as a firewall? The "keepalive" or ping may be avoiding this as well. It is common to see in other stateful or reused connection scenarios such as a jdbc connection pool. What does the jax-ws client app log or report?

Answer (score 1):

I went into further investigation since I was having the same problem.  What I found is that this is HTTP 1.1 default behavior.  from wikipedia([persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)):

> In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared
>   otherwise.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) The HTTP persistent connections do not use separate
>   keepalive messages, they just allow multiple requests to use a single
>   connection. However, the default connection timeout of Apache httpd
>   1.3 and 2.0 is as little as 15 seconds[2](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/HttpURLConnection.html)[3] and just 5 seconds for Apache httpd 2.2 and above.[4][5] The advantage of a short timeout is
>   the ability to deliver multiple components of a web page quickly while
>   not consuming resources to run multiple server processes or threads
>   for too long

So basically what is happening is that your client is closing the connection after it's idle for the configured amount of time(connection-timeout).  Jax-ws implements by default apache [HttpUrlConnection](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/HttpURLConnection.html) which has a preconfigured 15 seconds timeout.  In our client running on Weblogic 12.1.3 the following configuration worked for us:

```
final BindingProvider binding = (BindingProvider) port;
final Map<String, Object> ctx = binding.getRequestContext();
ctx.put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", requestTimeOut);
ctx.put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", connectTimeOut);
```